# Custom Segue Class for Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, storyboard, segue

A Standard / Forward Segue can be clicked on in the Storyboard builder and the style can be changed to Custom. At this point a Segue Class can be specified. However, this is not possible for an Unwind Segue. Unwind Segues only have Identifier and Action to specify. It reasons that their type is "Unwind Segue" but is there a way to create a custom Segue class for these Unwind Segues?

Comment: http://www.bencz.com/hacks/2014/02/07/custom-ios-segues-in-xcode-5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that in order to implement a custom unwind segue I had to subclass the UINavigationController and override this method as follows:

```
-(UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
UIViewController *controller = self.topViewController;
UIStoryboardSegue *unwindSegue;

if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourClassThatNeedsCustomUnwind class]]) {
    unwindSegue = [controller segueForUnwindingToViewController:toViewController fromViewController:fromViewController identifier:identifier];
}

if (unwindSegue) {
    return unwindSegue;
} else {
    return [super segueForUnwindingToViewController:toViewController fromViewController:fromViewController identifier:identifier];
}
}
```

Then in the UIViewController where the custom unwind segue is needed override this method:

```
 - (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
YourCustomUnwindSegue *segue = [[YourCustomUnwindSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier source:fromViewController destination:toViewController];
return segue;
 }
```

Lastly in your custom UIStoryboardSegue class just override the "-(void)perform:" method and put whatever animations (or in my case lack of animations) you need.

```
- (void)perform
{
UINavigationController *containerVC = (UINavigationController*)[self.destinationViewController parentViewController];
[containerVC popToViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Note: I implemented this in iOS8

Comment: You may want to define a protocol ViewControllerWithCustomUnwindProtocol with segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier: defined on it. Any ViewController requiring a custom unwind segue just implements that protocol (easy for VC's since the method already exists in base). Then your subclassed UINavController need only check for protocol implementation and will work for all custom VCs w/o code modification (more decoupled).

Comment: Thanks Joshcodes, when I get a free moment I'm going to circle back and see about implementing that.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to have a look at http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/ article. It explains custom segues in great detail.

Comment: I followed the explanation on custom unwind segues and that seems OK so far. But you should probably include those parts in this answer...

Comment: Page is no longer accessible